# how to beta reduction in lambda calculus?

Tags: lambda, calculus

I have a lambda expression that have a white space.
I just don't know about that case how to do.

```
 (λy.λz.λz.z y t) k (λx.x)
```

The above one is problem.

```
First, k reduction -> (λz.λz.z k t) (λx.x) and (λx.x) reduction 
-> λ(λx.x).(λx.x) k t -> k.k t ??????? what is problem in this case?
or k reduction first, than (λk.k t) (λx.x) -> (λx.x t) -> t ?
the below one is OK?
```